# AVPlayer's `currentItem` is always nil when set from an `onChange(of:)` event

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayer

I am trying to play a stream URL that is set from an `onChange` event. The URL appears correctly (non nil) in the closure, but AVPlayer's `currentItem` is always nil during render. What is going wrong here?

```
struct VideoPlayerContainerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var store: AppStore
    private var player = AVPlayer()
    @State private var urlToPlay: URL?
    @State private var playingUrl: URL?
    
    var body: some View {

            let currentPlayerUrl = ((player.currentItem?.asset) as? AVURLAsset)?.url
            print("asset loaded in the VideoPlayer ⬇")
            print(currentPlayerUrl ?? "no asset!") // This is always nil
        
        return ZStack {
            VideoPlayerView(player: player)
        }
        .onChange(of: self.store.state.videos.playingVideo?.stream?.best.url) {
            [oldValue = self.store.state.videos.playingVideo?.stream?.best.url] newValue in

            print("- - - - - - - - - - - - ")
            
            self.urlToPlay = newValue
            if (self.urlToPlay != self.playingUrl) {
                let newPlayerItem = self.urlToPlay != nil ? AVPlayerItem(url: self.urlToPlay!) : nil
                player.replaceCurrentItem(with: newPlayerItem)
                self.playingUrl = self.urlToPlay
                
                print("newPlayerItem ⬇")
                print(newPlayerItem ?? "nil")
                print("url that should play now ⬇")
                let currentPlayerUrl = ((player.currentItem?.asset) as? AVURLAsset)?.url
                print(currentPlayerUrl ?? "nil") // Not nil
            }
            
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    let player: AVPlayer
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
    }
}
```

Comment: `player` is getting recreated every time your view is re-rendered. If you want to have it be persistent across renders, store it in a `@State` variable. Normally, these are used for value types, but it will also work in this case.